# Java 1.8 is required for Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: java, java-8, oracle-sqldeveloper, java-7

I have installed java 1.7 oracle 11g successfully. All the environment variables are set. These are my configurations.

*1 - sql developer that I am using "sqldeveloper-4.1.0.19.07-no-jre".

2 - JAVA_HOME set to jdk1.7.0_79

3 - product.conf has the path of this java home(1.7).

4 - sqldeveloper.conf also has the entry of jdk(1.7) home.*

When I run sql developer, it tells me the minimum requirement is jdk 1.8, on one of my other machine, with same specs, it does not asks me anything. If anyone has any idea, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to state the obvious but… Oracle SQL Developer [requires Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sqldev-relnotes-41-2372786.html) – at least since [release 4.1.0](http://web.archive.org/web/20141225033838/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/sqldev-relnotes-41-2372786.html) in December 2014.

Your other machine is either running an older version, or running it on Java 8.